# I am relocating a sink. Can I leave the original plumbing in place and cap it?

Tags: plumbing

I am relocating a sink and I am rotating the tub (actually replacing the tub with a shower) in position and it will cover the area under which I have the drain for the current sink
Should I remove it prior to this or I can leave it where it is and cap it and hide it in the wall ?

Comment: If it feeds a floor drain, be sure that fhe floor drain is still being fed to avoid the trap drying out.

Comment: If I add (move) the sink somewhere else on the same drain wouldnt that take care of this?

Comment: yes, that would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cap it, but you have to use an ABS glue cap, not pressure fitted coloured caps.

If you are cutting anything back, past any T or Y connectors, make sure you do not sever the dry-vent connection to the rest of the plumbing.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to cap it and leave it within the wall.